# How can I use useMemo dependent on the webapi

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-usememo

I have a webapi invoked that is working properly:

```
const [pItem, setPItem] = useState([]);
const [weight, setWeight] = useReducer(weightHandler, 0.0);
useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    let mounted = true;
    (async function () {
        await getPlantInfoById(itemId)
            .then(item => {
                if (mounted) {
                    setPItem(item)
                    setLoading(false);
                }
            })
    })();
    return () => { mounted = false; }
}, [itemId])
```

Here pItem contains data now I have another filled called weight(which can be changed by a user) .

So I need some calculations according to the weight changes:

```
const PaymentCalculator = function () {
    const [item] = [...pItem];
    const priceWithDiscount = DiscountCalc(item.price, item.discount);
    const divideWeight = weight / item.weight;
    const result = (divideWeight * priceWithDiscount) * 1000;

    return result;
}
const use = useMemo(() => PaymentCalculator(), [weight])
```

But it seems PaymentCalculator invoked before useEffect !!

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you examine the contents of `paymentCalculator` you'll see you've more than just `weight` as a dependency.

```
const PaymentCalculator = function () {
  const [item] = [...pItem];
  const priceWithDiscount = DiscountCalc(item.price, item.discount);
  const divideWeight = weight / item.weight;
  const result = (divideWeight * priceWithDiscount) * 1000;

  return result;
}
```

`pItem` is also a dependency!

Initially `pItem` is an empty array, and since all hooks are called on each render cycle, this would mean that `item` is undefined on the initial render and accessing `item.price` and `item.discount` will throw an error for attempting to "access X of undefined".

Add `pItem` to the dependency array and provide a fallback value.

```
const paymentCalculator = function() {
  const [item = {}] = [...pItem];

  const priceWithDiscount = discountCalc(item.price, item.discount);
  const divideWeight = weight / item.weight;
  const result = (divideWeight * priceWithDiscount) * 1000;

  return result;
}
```

...

```
const use = useMemo(() => PaymentCalculator(), [pItem, weight]);
```